# $X\subset \mathbb N$ is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $X\subset \mathbb N$ is countable, in another words, if there is a injection $i:X\to \mathbb N$ then $X$ is countable. I know this is true intuitively but I couldn't find any easy proof of this fact. My attempt is to find another injection $g:\mathbb N\to X$ and use Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

I need help to find a simple proof of $X\subset \mathbb N$ is countable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When $X$ is finite, there is nothing to prove, so we assume $X$ infinite.
By the [Well-Ordering Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle), $X$ contains a least element, denoted as $x_1.$ Then $X-\{x_1\}$ has a least element, denoted as $x_2,$ and so on. Then you find an injection: $\mathbb N\rightarrow X,$ sending $n$ to $x_n.$
Hope this helps.